# Twitter Bootstrap with 1024px fixed width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My project needs me to create website with 1024px fixed width. How can I use Twitter Bootstrap which uses 960px fixed width method to adjust to 1024px width.

Is there any downsides of having 1024px width websites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create .container class and assign it width of 1024px .

```
.container{
            width:1024px;
           }
```

and you will have to rewrite classes according to it .

Downsize can be with small monitors there can be a scrollbar in browsers.Suppose you create your pages at 1024×768, they will not fit into the screen of a visitor that has set his/her resolution to 800×600.

But usually these days people have bigger screen with good resolution , so you go with the 1024px size .

Answer (score 2):

You can actually customize Twitter Bootstrap using the [Customization form](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html). Else, you can set the CSS here:

```
.container{
    width: 1024px;
}
```